# styling a div with span and <b> tag

Tags: html, css

I have a div with two elements

```
 <div style={{color:'black',justifyContent:'center',marginTop:'1.3rem'}}>
   <span>
     <b>
       <u>{galleyNo}</u>
     </b>
   </span>
   <br />
   <span>{galleyItem}</span>
 </div>
```

I am trying to give styles two the inner elements.I need underline for the text inside `<b>` tag but giving it in `<u>` tag doesn't provide me the desired result. Also I need to center align the texts inside the `div`.

What will be a probable css for these elements ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `text-align: center;` to the container `<div>`.

```css
div {

outline: 1px dotted;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div style={{color:'black',justifyContent:'center',marginTop:'1.3rem'}}>
  <span>
    <b ><u>{galleyNo}</u></b>
  </span>
  <br/>
  <span>{galleyItem}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your desired result something like this? (It seems you have not posted a lot of your code into this, but here's what I've got so far with what you gave me [with cleaned-up code for clarity].)

```html
<div style="color: black; justify-content: center; margin-top: 1.3rem;">
  <span>
    <b>
      <u>
        {galleyNo}
      </u>
    </b>
  </span>
  <br>
  <span>{galleyItem}</span>
</div>
```

I'm not sure in what way it is not giving you your desired result, perhaps I'll need to see something in your original code?

And as for your centering of the text, this is all that's required:

```html
<div style="color: black; margin-top: 1.3rem; text-align: center;">
  <span>
    <b>
      <u>
        {galleyNo}
      </u>
    </b>
  </span>
  <br>
  <span>{galleyItem}</span>
</div>
```

You used [`justify-content`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_justify-content.php) instead of [`text-align`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.php).

P.S. Your `<span>` tags are doing nothing unless you have some CSS for them. 
For example:

```
span {font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;}
```

[The `<span>` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp) doesn't have any default styles, and I don't see any JavaScript, etc. to do something with them. I would say they are doing nothing and that you should remove them, but I actually suggest that you not use the `<b>` and `<u>` tags, but rather the `<strong>` and `<em>` tags respectively, or do something like give the `<span>` tag `class="bold underline"` and add this CSS:

```
.bold {font-weight: bold;}
.underline {text-decoration: underline;}
```

or add the CSS inline like this:

```
style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; /* other styles, etc. */"
```